# Js input type="file" частично не работает код

Tags: javascript, файлы, input

Здравствуйте. Я не знаток js прошел курсы и практикуюсь. в инете был найдет скрипт отвечающий моим задачам на 90%. доработал немного, но возникли ошбки. Прошу помочь.

1-я. Проблема в том что когда я загружаю файлы пример: я загрузил 1 файл он уменя под номером 1, если я загружу еще один то и тот будет под номером один. Необходимо чтобы шли по порядку.
2-я. Проблема если на странице два input type="file" второй не работает.

Господа СПАСАЙТЕ )

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaljalet/2rnpruLk/3/

скрипт ниже по ссылке.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  var y = 1;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = ['<strong>' + (y++) + ' -</strong>', escape(theFile.name), '<span class="fa fa-times removeLi" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(li, null);
        $('.removeLi').click(function(e) {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        });
      };


    })(f);
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('logoBefore').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="form-block logo-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-logo">
          <form action="" method="post" id="formLogo">
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <div class="form-control file-upload" id="logoBefore" name="logoBefore" data-text="Varsa daha önceki logonuzu (ai/eps/psd) formatında yükleyiniz.">
                <input type="file" id="LogoUpload" multiple>
              </div>
              <ul class="col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 uploaded-file" id="list"></ul>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <div class="form-control file-upload" id="logoOrnek" name="logoOrnek" data-text="Varsa daha önceki logonuzu (ai/eps/psd) formatında yükleyiniz.">
                <input type="file" id="LogoUpload" multiple>
              </div>
              <ul class="col-sm-7 col-md-5 col-lg-4 uploaded-file" id="list"></ul>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: к инпутам попробуй добавить name="file_arr[]"

Comment: На странице не может быть двух элементов с одинаковым id. А у вас такие есть. Все остальные проблемы, наверно, следуют из этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вынесите `var y = 1;` из тела функции
2. На загрузку со второго input не висит слушатель. Нужно добавить `document.getElementById('logoOrnek').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);`

Поскольку файлы нужно отображать в разных списках, необходимо еще несколько изменений:

```
var y = {list: 1, list2: 1};
function handleFileSelect(evt, list_id) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerHTML = ['<strong>' + (y[list_id]++) + ' -</strong>', escape(theFile.name), '<span class="fa fa-times removeLi" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>'].join('');
          document.getElementById(list_id).insertBefore(li, null);
            $('.removeLi').click(function (e) {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
document.getElementById('logoBefore').addEventListener('change', function(event){handleFileSelect(event, 'list');}, false);
document.getElementById('logoOrnek').addEventListener('change', function(event){handleFileSelect(event, 'list2');}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2rnpruLk/6/

Comment: супер. Как раз 

после document.getElementById('logoBefore').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  добавил document.getElementById('logoOrnek').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

и ваш коментарий пришел. Спасибо огромнейшее. Вчера мучался по страшному, но многое понял. Конечно еще много надо потеть. учиться. 
Еще один вопрос.
Каждый раз при добавлении инпута мне надо будеть в js добавлять строку document.getElementById('logoOrnek').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false); с заменой id и он будет работать?

Comment: Да, но по хорошему лучше вешать обработчик на сам input, а не на div

Comment: он там и был раньше. это я походу в время опытов каким-то образом в div запихал и не только обработчик на div повесил, еще и name туда засунул))) . Сейчас исправлю. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: само детище: http://moorweb.moorsoftware.com/creative/logo.html только на старте